# Concatenar dois sql

Tags: sql, select, firebird

Tenho os registros:

```
|DT_OBS  | DESC_OBS | COD_TURNO | COD_PERIODO|
|01.10.16|  TESTE 01|     1     |   1        |
|01.10.16|  TESTE 02|     2     |   1        |
|01.10.16|  TESTE 03|     1     |   2        |
|02.10.16|  TESTE 04|     1     |   1        |
|02.10.16|  TESTE 05|     1     |   2        |
```

Quero que me retorne:

```
|DT_OBS  | DESC_OBS |
|01.10.16|  TESTE 01TESTE 02TESTE 03
|02.10.16|  TESTE 04TESTE 05
```

Como faço junção das DESC_OBS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Desde a versão 2.1, a função `LIST()` faz o que você quer:

```
SELECT
  DT_OBS,
  LIST(DESC_OBS) AS LISTA_OBS
FROM
  registros
GROUP BY
  DT_OBS
```

O `LIST()` do FireBird é similar ao `GROUP_CONCAT()` do MySQL, porém, sem a opção de ordenar os resultados.